# Alternative for f10 key in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

In my HP laptop, I use f10 key to open BIOS. I got some problem with f10 key and it's not working now. Instead can I setup a shortcut for f10 key i.e a combination of two or more keys so that they achieve the same effect of pressing f10?

Comment: Don't think so because it happens before Ubuntu is running.  You would have to reprogram Bios, probably a bad idea.  Check your grub listings, because sometimes there is a line, not sure of wording but something with setting.  This should take you to bios if you are using UEFI bios.